#  Ambiguous occurrence `Just'  

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghc, ghci, haskell-platform

I am an absolute beginner. Going through LYAH using emacs.

My current Set up:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Use Experience - beginner)
- GNU Emacs 23 (Use Experience - beginner)

  - able to work in haskell major mode

Finding difficult to follow instructions (to bring haskell libraries) at [Point 2 described here.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Installing_haskell-mode)

Also need guidance to enable [Scion IDE](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs#Scion).

**Problem:**

.hs code

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

While running the code, I get following error:

Please ignore typo error, Originally posted:

```
*Main> just "Haha"
```

interactive>:339:1: Not in scope: `just'

**This is the real error** (added after Tikhon Jelvis' comment):

```
*Main> Just "Haha"  
interactive>:341:1:  
    Ambiguous occurrence `Just'  
    It could refer to either `Main.Just',    
                             defined at /home/optimight/baby.hs:89:26  
                          or `Prelude.Just',  
                             imported from `Prelude' at /home/optimight/baby.hs:1:1  
                             (and originally defined in `Data.Maybe')
```

Comment: **baby steps** -- ha ha ha, first time I see an honest request to spoon feed. cool. :)

Comment: Erm, `just` has to start with a capital letter. So you should have written `Just "Haha"`. Was that a typo in the question or what you actually entered to GHCi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your error just tells you that there are *two* possible versions of `Just` and GHCi does not know which one to pick.

Every Haskell program implicitly imports a whole bunch of functions and data types. These form the "prelude". One of these types is `Maybe`. This means that every single program already has access to a type just like the one you defined, with exactly the same names.

You can overcome this in two ways. The best option would be to just choose different names:

```
data MyMaybe a = MyJust a | MyNothing
```

(I'm sure you can come up with better names than that though :P.)

The other option would be to import the Prelude explicitly, hiding `Maybe`:

```
import Prelude hiding (Maybe (..))
```

This line at the top of your program just tells Haskell to import everything it normally imports *except* `Maybe` and all of it's constructors (`Just` and `Nothing`).

Now you will run into one more problem: GHCi does not know how to render a value of your `Maybe` type into a string to show on the prompt. You will get an error like this:

```
<interactive>:1:1:
No instance for (Show (Maybe [Char]))
  arising from a use of `print'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Maybe [Char]))
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

What you need to do is tell the compiler how a `Maybe` value looks as a string. Happily, this is extremely easy. In fact, it's *so* easy even the computer can do it! If you define your type as:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing deriving (Show)
```

then the compiler will write a `show` function (which is basically `toString` from other languages) for you. Now your original statement (`Just "Haha"`) should work properly.

Also: enabling Scion is a completely different question entirely. I don't think it's worth bothering with it until you've learned more Haskell and are actually working on some sort of larger project. For now, the standard Haskell mode should be more than enough.

Comment: Sir, My humble request to add one more option: It was my mistake that I was declaring 'data Maybe a' which is already declared and comes in Prelude. One can opt to - not declare it explicitly but directly test the ' Just "Haha" '.

Comment: When I run `data MyMaybe a = MyJust a | MyNothin` it compiles fine.  When I then run `MyJust "blank"` I get an error "No Instance for (Show..."  I can kind of understand why I would get this error, but Learn You A Haskell shows a different sort of behavior than the error, can you explain why?

Comment: I don't know what LYAH shows for this problem. The issue comes up because `MyMaybe` does not have a `Show` instance: you can either implement one manually or add a `deriving Show` clause to the data definition.